# Overlay option to the left

Tags: jquery, css

I was trying to make an overlay with jquery 1.7.1, like the one Nokia uses in its website:
http://www.nokia.com/us-en/products/products/

I'm using jpmodal: http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#examples

but I had no luck

Anyone knows how to get an effect like the one from Nokia site?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com), specifically their [modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal).

Comment: I tried with jquery ui but now I have a problem implementing it.

I want to use this effect with a lot of items, a list, so my problem is how I can make this script work for every item in the list, having into account that the href is inside the container div.

I think this can explain my point more clear:

http://jsfiddle.net/viciosogb/kPzjB/